# What damage could Gasoline "95E10" do to my Yaris?

Tags: fuel-system

In Europe, the standard was to have 95e5 fuel (RON 95 gasoline with 5% ethanol). New guidlines however, make that countries are switching to selling 95e10 (10% ethanol). Finland e.g. (where I live) has made the switch, while other countries like the Netherlands are waiting it out, to see what problems will arise.

Especially in Germany there was quite some uproar, as some manufacturers were proclaiming that the e10 fuel is bad for the cars. A lot of people there are fuelling 98e5 now instead (even though it's more expensive). Also here in Finland some people make that decision.

I'm driving myself a 2010 Toyota Yaris. Will there be any negative consequences to any parts of my engine if I continue to use 95e10? Is it better to switch to 98e5 instead?

Answer (score 2):

Most if not all modern cars will run on 10% Ethanol without any damage to the engine or fuel system. Check you owners manual as it probably gives you this information. It is/was called [gasohol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_ethanol_fuel_mixtures#E10_or_less) here in the states and was popular in the 80's (if my memory serves me correctly).

This [Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_ethanol_fuel_mixtures#Modifications_to_engines) shows the various concentrations and the modifications required, it indicates that a Carbureted vehicle may need modification to run on E10, in my experience this has not been the case.